# Picture/Logo in Header Quarto qmd to pdf

Tags: r, pdf, latex, quarto

I want to place a logo in the header of the first page of an article(`documentclass: scrartcl`), but I want the header to change from the second page onward. I have tried the following solution:

```
---
title: "Logo in Header"
format: 
   pdf: 
      include-in-header: 
         text: |
            \usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
            \clearpairofpagestyles
            \cohead[\includegraphics[width=5cm]{my_logo.png}]{Header from page 2 onward}
            
---

Page 1

\newpage

Page 2
```

Unfortunately, I am receiving the following error message:

```
compilation failed- error
LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.80 ...cludegraphics[width=5cm]{visana_logo.png}]
                                                  {Header from page 2 onward}
```

When I replace the image with text, it works:

```
---
title: "Logo in Header"
format: 
   pdf: 
      include-in-header: 
         text: |
            \usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
            \clearpairofpagestyles
            \cohead[Header page 1]{Header from page 2 onward}
            
---

Page 1

\newpage

Page 2
```

It also works when I remove the width argument for the image:

```
---
title: "Logo in Header"
format: 
   pdf: 
      include-in-header: 
         text: |
            \usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
            \clearpairofpagestyles
            \cohead[\includegraphics{my_logo.png}]{Header from page 2 onward}
            
---

Page 1

\newpage

Page 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting errors because the closing square bracket `]` from `width[..]` is being parsed as optional argument terminator for `\cohead`.

So,
`\includegraphics[width=5cm` is being passed as the optional argument to `\cohead`. So to avoid this, enclose the whole optional argument content within a curly braces. [See this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99495/261065) excellent Q/A thread from TexStackExchange for details.

Therefore, just put the `includegraphics[width=5cm]{test.png}` within a extra pair of curly braces `{}` and it will work!

```
---
title: "Logo in Header"
format: 
   pdf:
     include-in-header: 
         text: |
            \usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
            \clearpairofpagestyles
            \cohead[{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{test.png}}]{Header from page 2 onward}
            
---

Page 1

\newpage

Page 2
```